# Reindent XML via keyboard shortcut

Tags: notepad++

I am browsing through hundreds of xml files.  When I open them in notepad++ I have to do an HTML Tidy->re-indent XML with each one:

[image: Notepad Reindent]

The step does not take too long for one file, but it adds up with lots and lots of files.

Is there a way to put that on a keyboard shortcut in notepad++?

Comment: You should be able to do this in the Plugin commands tab of Shortcut Mapper, but that list is a complete pain to wade through and I can't find this particular command. Why not record a macro instead? Then you can have a keyboard shortcut run that macro.

Comment: @BoltClock - I tried the macro tack before posting.  I hit record, ran the html tidy then hit stop.  I then un-did the tidy and ran the playback for the macro.  Maybe I am inept, but this left me with a very corrupt file (lots and lots of Unicode that was not there when I just ran the Re-Indent).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this in

Settings > Shortcut Mapper

Go to the 'Plugin Commands' section and find row 196: D: Tidy (Most recent HTMLTIDY.CFG)

You can map this command to any key combination you desire by selecting that row in the table and pressing the 'modify' button.

edit: You could also install the [XML Tools Plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/) for Notepad++ and this will give you a shortcut of Ctrl+Alt+Shift+b but I think the native solution is probably satisfactory in most cases.