# DataContractJsonSerializer human-readable json

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

Basically a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2661063/1997232) question with one notable difference - I have to use `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

A simple

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Person));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
    ...
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

produced single line json, e.g. (when saved in file)

```
...{"blah":"v", "blah2":"v2"}...
```

What are the options to make it

```
...
{
    "blah":"v", 
    "blah2":"v2"
}
...
```

I can think of post-processing... Is there an easier option? E.g. similar to formatting [xml produced by DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739169/1997232) ?

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    // "beautify"
    using (var writer = new SomeKindOfWriter(stream))
        serializer.WriteObject(writer, obj);
    ...
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```

Is there a way to make such `SomeKindOfWriter` to beautify json when needed?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do it with `DataContractJsonSerializer` without some external function/library to do it.

Comment: Well, I can do post-processing right now, but it sounds stupid: parsing json back (in some way). I'd be happy with answer where there is something in-between of memory stream and json getting values and being able to format them. Similar to [`XmlWriter`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/739169/1997232) if that is possible.

Comment: Are you forces to use exactly type DataContractJsonSerializer? Can it be another class derived from XmlObjectSerializer?

Comment: This post is wrongly marked as a duplicate. The post this is being linked to does not show how to achieve a user-readable format using `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings`, which is THE question being asked here.

Comment: @Veverke, right. But there were other issues and I ended up using json.net, so disregards I mentioned duplicate myself in question when someone see its this way I don't mind. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21407175/1997232) is the solution I am using now.

Comment: @Sinatr: at least give the guy below an upvote, he's the one who tackled the original problem, as far as I understand :) (and the one who helped me, after ending up in this post for the problem exacted by the post's title)

Answer (score 10):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38538454/6627992

You may use following standard method for getting formatted Json

*JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool ownsStream, bool indent, string indentChars)*

Only set *"indent==true"*

Try something like this

```
    public readonly DataContractJsonSerializerSettings Settings = 
            new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings
            { UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true };

    public void Keep<TValue>(TValue item, string path)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                //var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                try
                {
                    using (var writer = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonWriter(
                        stream, Encoding.UTF8, true, true, "  "))
                    {
                        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, Settings);
                        serializer.WriteObject(writer, item);
                        writer.Flush();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Pay your attention to lines

```
    var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    ....
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
```

For some kinds of xml-serializers you should use InvariantCulture to avoid exception during deserialization on the computers with different Regional settings. For example, invalid format of double or DateTime sometimes cause them.

For deserializing

```
    public TValue Revive<TValue>(string path, params object[] constructorArgs)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                //var currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                try
                {
                    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(type, Settings);
                    var item = (TValue) serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                    if (Equals(item, null)) throw new Exception();
                    return item;
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                    return (TValue) Activator.CreateInstance(type, constructorArgs);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return (TValue) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (TValue), constructorArgs);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!